# Atualizar $scope no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Galera o problema, em um modo geral, é que não consigo pegar  informações recebidas em um controlador e aplicar no meu html, quando eu tento ao invés de printar a variável na tela fica vazio, quando dou um console.log em meu escopo, as informações estão lá disponíveis, mas elas não são colocadas na tela quando eu preciso.

Então, eu possuo uma search de usuário muito parecido com o do facebook.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" ng-controller="pesquisas">
   <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" ng-keyup="search()" ng-keydown="search()" ng-model = "pesquisa.nome_usuario" class="form-control pesquisar_input" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                    </div>
                    <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pesquisar</button> -->
                    <div class = "resultado_pesquisa" ng-show="resultado>0">
                        <ul>
                            <li class = "linha_usuario_pesquisa"ng-repeat = "usuario in usuarios " data-refresh-list data-toggle="modal" href='#avaliacao' ng-click="dados_usuario(usuario)" ng-controller="avaliacao" >
                                <div class = "imagem_perfil_masculino pull-left" ng-show="usuario.sexo_usuario==1">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user usuario_masculino" ></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "imagem_perfil_feminino pull-left" ng-show="usuario.sexo_usuario==0">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user usuario_masculino" ></span>
                                </div>
                                <span class = "nome_linha_usuario pull-left" >{{usuario.nome_usuario}}</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

O controlador que executa a pesquisa é este.

```
$scope.search = function(){



        if($scope.pesquisa.nome_usuario.length >0){
            $http.post('usuarios/consult_user',$scope.pesquisa)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.resultado = 1;
                $scope.usuarios = data;


            });

        }
        else{
            $scope.resultado = 0;
            $scope.usuarios = 0;
        }
}
```

Onde inicia minha lista  posso clicar sobre ela, e enviar os dados do usuário através de um ng-click, o meu controlador que recebe estas informações é o seguinte.

```
 app.controller('avaliacao', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.dados = {};
        $scope.dados_usuario = function (usuario) {
            $scope.dados = usuario;
        });
    });
```

Ao mesmo tempo que esta função é requisitada é aberto o seguinte modal, onde a ideia é inserir todas as informações do usuário resgatadas.

```
<div class="modal fade " id="avaliacao"  data-backdrop="static" ng-controller="avaliacao">
            <div class="modal-dialog full-screen">
                <div class="modal-content" >
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top nav-interna">

                            <div class = "imagem_perfil_masculino_interno pull-left" >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user usuario_masculino" ></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="pull-left nome_aluno_interno" ><h4 >{{dados.nome_usuario}}</h4></span>


                            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, coloque todo o código acredito ser mais fácil te ajudar assim !!!

Comment: Sim, coloque o html senão fica impossível decifrar. Mas já de cara é muito estranho uma função amarrada a um ng-click "receber" dados. Geralmente, os dados estão atrelados as variáveis colocados no formulário via ng-model.

Comment: Poste o seu código html, ficará mais fácil de achar o erro.

Comment: O seu código tem vários "cheiros" de que você está misturando as bolas da maneira jQuery/Bootstrap de fazer as coisas com o jeito Angular. Um problema claro é que você não deve ter o mesmo controller para 2 views diferentes. Aconselharia você a dar uma olhada no projeto Angular UI Bootstrap ou AngularStrap e ver uma maneira alternativa mais "Angulariana" de fazer o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: @Dema pode explicar quais são os ¨cheiros¨? Quanto a ¨um controller para uma view¨, isso não é uma norma "Angulariana".

Comment: @Bertrand Na verdade, Angular encoraja que você quebre a sua página em diversos componentes menores e que cada componente desse tenha um controller associado, inter-conectados pelo mecanismo de herança do Scope. Mas reutilizar o mesmo controller para 2 views diferentes é algo incomum, que geralmente leva a um controller mais complexo do que deveria ser.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que `$scope.dados` pertence ao scope do controlador `avaliacao` e a função search pertence ao controlador `pesquisas`. `Avaliacao` é filho de `pesquisas`, logo `pesquisas` não tem acesso ao scope do filho.

Utilizador o $rootScope para ultrapassar este problema é uma má prática ([veja este post no SO em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573023/is-binding-objects-to-angulars-rootscope-in-a-service-bad))

A forma *"angulariana"* de partilhar modelos entre controladores é utilizar um ["service"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Veja aqui este [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/LziusVZnNbiFMRGZaMKD?p=preview) como exemplo do que pretende.

```js
      angular
        .module("myApp", [])
        .factory('utilizadores', [function() {
            return [
              { nome: 'joao', email: 'joao@foo.bar' },
              { nome: 'maria', email: 'maria@foo.bar' },
              { nome: 'rita', email: 'rita@foo.bar' }
            ];
        }])
        .controller('lista', ['$scope', 'utilizadores', function($scope, utilizadores) {
          $scope.utilizadores = utilizadores;
          $scope.pesquisado = false;
        }])
        
        .controller('pesquisa', ['$scope', 'utilizadores', function($scope, utilizadores) {
          $scope.suser = {nome: '',email: ''};
          var list = utilizadores;
          console.log(list);
          $scope.pesquisar = function (name) {
            for (var i=0; i<list.length; ++i) {
              if (list[i].nome === name) {
                $scope.suser = list[i];
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }])
        
        .directive('userDetails', function() {
              return {
                template: 'Nome: {{suser.nome}} Email: {{suser.email}}'
              };
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="lista">
    <span ng-repeat="utilizador in utilizadores">
      Nome: {{ utilizador.nome }} - mail: {{ utilizador.email }}<br>
    </span>
    </div>
  
  
    <div ng-controller="pesquisa">
      Pesquisar: <input type="text" ng-model="name"> <button ng-click="pesquisar(name)">Pesquisar</button>
      
      <div user-details>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso aqui, na sua linha 45, resolve o que muita gente procura ->     $scope.suser = {nome: '',email: ''};

Answer (score 1):

Se o escopo possui o valor correto mas os dados não aparecem na UI é porque o digest cycle nao ocorreu uma vez que os dados retornaram e por isso Angular não atualiza os vínculos de dados (data binds).

Isso provavelmente ocorre porque o request dos dados do usuário é assíncrono (mais detalhes sobre search() seria útil).

Experimenta colocar o código abaixo depois que os dados do usuário forem adicionados ao escopo.

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Esse comando inicia um digest cycle e faz com que Angular verifique se alguma mudança ocorreu, caso encontre alguma diferença ele efetua as atualizações necessárias, que no seu caso são os vínculos de dados na UI.

Uma dica, no formulário de pesquisa você não precisa usar as diretivas ng-keyup e ng-keydown juntas, uma delas é suficiente.

Comment: Quando adiciono esta linha é me apresentado o seguinte error.http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply

Comment: Resolvi o problema com a utilização do $rootScope :D

Comment: Não é esse o problema. As variáveis dentro do $scope são "watched" por defeito. O problema é que dados_usuario pertence a um scope diferente.

Comment: @user7443 Não deve utilizar o $rootScope para expor modelos entre os controladores (veja http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573023/is-binding-objects-to-angulars-rootscope-in-a-service-bad)

Answer (score 0):

primeira vez contribuindo com o conteúdo...

Usei o método aplicado pelo usuário Bertrand, mas usando desta forma $rootScope.$apply();

E é preciso analisar em seu código onde colocar esta linha de código, pois se for usado em uma execução que o $digest() ainda esta em progresso não irá funcionar.

obrigado pela dica.